# Comma after a dialogue tag to avoid confusion?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> “Joe,” I called, the moment I could open my mouth. “An army. There’s an army out there."

My beta reader is unsure about the comma after 'I called'. I think it should be included because 'I called the moment...' could throw the reader, if only for a second. However, he found the comma very jarring.

Should it be included or not?

*Note:* I looked at the help center, and I believe this question is on topic, as it is a specific question about a particular point in my text, as mentioned under 'How can I ask about checking my text?' However, if it's still off topic, just let me know.

Comment: I agree with the reader, do not include.

Comment: "I'm not sure," he said, not knowing enough about grammar to speak with confidence.

Comment: One could argue that you are right about the need to avoid a garden-path sentence. Punctuation is there to help parse correctly, in the first instance. “Joe,” I called as soon as I could." is probably better without the comma, but with a temporal expression headed by 'the moment', a comma is at least a valid option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not be included.

If the structure were flipped, it would make sense:

*The moment I could open my mouth, I called.*

That, however, does not really work for denoting dialogue:

*"Joe," The moment I could open my mouth, I called.*

May I suggest altering the phrase?

*"Joe," I called as soon as I could open my mouth.*